# specifying header collapse depth in rmarkdown floating table of contents

Tags: r-markdown

I'm writing an R markdown document with 4 levels of headers, and I want up to the H2 header for all sections to be shown in the floating table of contents by default. It's fine if the lower level headers expand while scrolling, but I want the TOC to collapse back to just 2 levels afterward.

Example document below:

```
# section
## subsection

# section
## subsection
### subsubsection
## subsection
## subsection

# section
## subsection
### subsubsection
### subsubsection
#### subsubsubsection
```

---

Here's some of the yaml headers that I thought could get what I want: (I want html and for figures to be auto-numbered so I'm using `bookdown::html_document2` as the output format, but open to suggestions.)

Attempt 1:

```
output:
  toc: true
  toc_float:
    toc_depth: 2
    collapsed: false
```

Confusingly(?), up to H3 headers are numbered. H4 headers don't show up in the TOC nor are they numbered.

Attempt 2:

```
output:
  toc: true
  toc_float:
    collapse: subsection
    collapsed: false
```

So close to what I want (only the subsection headers show in the TOC, lower headers expand upon scrolling), except that the TOC is collapsed to the H1 headers (even with `collapsed: false`).

Some other relevant solutions that aren't quite what I want:

- haven't tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73874758/r-markdown-toc-depth-only-certain-level) as I want to retain the H1 levels
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860859/collapsing-minor-levels-of-floating-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown-html-document) is also basically what I want, except I'd like to be the default behaviour of the TOC/not to not have to achieve it with a button.